# MediaPlayer/MediaRecorder Sound Quality Awful?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to develop a recording device, but when I play it back it sounds awful. It's all gargled and sounds like I'm really far away.

Here is the code. I've looked at trying to change the Encoder, bit rate, and sampling rate, but nothing seems to fix the gargle. I've looked around for other posts on this problem, but haven't found anything. Anyone help?

Also, I realize this is two different objects, but I'm not sure how to  check if it's the recorder or the player that's the issue. Ideas on that would be nice too!

```
MediaRecorder mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC);
mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(1280);
mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(4400);
mRecorder.setOutputFile(_audioFilename);


MediaPlayer media = new MediaPlayer();
try {
        media.setDataSource(task.getAudio());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
try {
        media.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    media.start();
```

EDIT:
Download of File https://sites.google.com/site/chasebusackersfilecabinet/home/ProxiVoiceOver3.mp4?attredirects=0&d=1

Or Here is it on Youtube (might not work):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=va0wlupsuPA&feature=youtu.be

Could it just be the emulator?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here

```
mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(1280);
mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(4400);
```

The bit rate is the amount of bits per second you would like the audio to be encoded to. For instance, if you wanted your recorded audio file to be ~1MB per second, you should set it to `133333` (1000000 bytes per minute * 8 bits per byte / 60 seconds per minute). This should be a target value for the encoding algorithm, I *think* that with AAC if you have some room to change that according to your needs and desired quality.

Sampling rate is the amount of frames per second of the playback, usually you want to set it to `44100`. That's a default value because humans are able to perceive frequencies up to 20KHz, if you sample the sound at slightly more than 40KHz you would be able to reproduce all the audible frequencies, for humans.

Comment: Sounds better. But now it sounds like there's almost static behind the sound. Any other improvements?

Comment: What I used in the past was that configuration, ~1MB per second at 44100 and the sound was OK. What you could try is to play with the values a bit, if that doesn't help I would suggest to record your sound uncompressed first. If you still hear artifacts in the uncompressed audio, then you will know that the problem is not the encoding format.

Comment: Still can't get it. I've tried all sorts of encoding formats. Here is a download link of one of the files I recorded: https://sites.google.com/site/chasebusackersfilecabinet/home/ProxiVoiceOver3.mp4?attredirects=0&d=1

Comment: Ah of course it could be the emulator, didn't you try on an actual device?

Comment: The current device that I have is APK 10. Way too old for this app or any app really. Been trying to get it updated.

Comment: If you mean that your device is running Android 2.3 then it's quite old indeed, my last suggestion is to check if the emulator can actually record (using an x86 emulator) with another app. If that works than lower the quality of your recording, say 11025Hz with a bit rate of ~100kB per minute.

Comment: hey @cwbusacker I just checked an app I did not long ago, with the emulator is picking up my laptop's microphone but the quality is not good, on the phone it records good quality though

Answer (score 0):

very low bitrate was mentioned already but not audio codec:

`MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC` - works only with audio + video recording

You should use `MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC` if you record only audio